# Django Error: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'order'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to render out the get_cart_total to the email template I'm working on, which gets sent when the success view is triggered and the boolean is True, currently it gets an error message saying 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'order', what's causing this and how do I fix it?
Model

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150)

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def get_cart_total(self):
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.get_total for item in orderitems])
        return total
```

Views

```
def success(request):
    if order.complete == True:
        email = request.user.customer.email
        
        #error
        cart_total = request.order.get_cart_total
        
        html_message = render_to_string('check/emails/test.html', {'cart_total': cart_total})
        recipient_list = [email, ]
        send_mail( subject, plain_message, email_from, recipient_list, html_message=html_message )
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
    File "D:\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    File "D:\test\shop\views.py", line 364, in success
        cart_total = request.order.get_cart_total
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'order'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access order from request. TRy to remove request ?

```py
def success(request):
    if order.complete == True:
        email = request.user.customer.email
        
        #error
        cart_total = order.get_cart_total
        
        html_message = render_to_string('check/emails/test.html', {'cart_total': cart_total})
        recipient_list = [email, ]
        send_mail( subject, plain_message, email_from, recipient_list, html_message=html_message )
```